# c++ safe counting backwards to zero for "auto" integral type

Tags: c++

Let `expression` be something which type is integral, known during compile-time, maybe signed, maybe unsigned. Is it safe to count backward to zero following way (assuming that actual value of expression is non-negative)?

```
for(auto i = expression; i!= static_cast<decltype(i)>(-1); --i) {
  //something
}
```

Comment: Why use auto if a for loop? The chances to obtain undefined behaviour are  really high.

Comment: There's no need for that cast there, unless you are just trying to suppress compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe. But in my opinion, it is difficult to read and the safety/correctness is not necessarily intuitive (after all, why would you even ask otherwise). I propose:

```
for(auto i = expression; i-- > 0;)
```

(Also known as the "goes to" operator, when formatted differently: `i --> 0`).

---

Edit: As pointed out, this doesn't have exactly the same behaviour as the loop in question. The initial value of `expression` is not iterated, instead the loop will start from `expression - 1` (and therefore there will be exactly `expression` number of iterations).

Comment: loop is supposed to be done for `i` = `expression` as well, so you should write `auto i = expression+1`. Personally, I find this way less readable, but of course it's a matter of test. Anyway, thank you for confirming that my variant is safe.

Comment: @DmitryJ oh, you are correct about the initial iteration. Good point.

Comment: Not sure about this +1 part. What if expression evaluates to std::numeric_limits::max<decltype(i)>?

Comment: @Tomek indeed, this approach can not handle that case. Depends on the context whether that is a problem. The most ideal case to use this is if you simply want `expression` number of iterations, rather than numbers starting from `expression` (which isn't exactly the behaviour of the loop in question).

Answer (score 1):

It can actually be quite dangerous because you allow `expression` to potentially be negative. If this happens, your code will start counting from the value of `expression` to negative infinity, which is undefined behaviour (nobody knows what will happen after `i` hits the integer limit). You basically have a for loop without a break clause.

Comment: Instead of an infinite loop, the behaviour would be undefined.